# Playstation Network API to get information?

Tags: sony, playstation

Is it possible to get a Playstation network API working on a site? I'm wanting to create a site where PSN users can join online competitions using their PSN name

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a PHP wrapper for the PSN API. It is called psn-php by Tustin and is the only one I have found online that is actively maintained. Link to GitHub:

https://github.com/Tustin/psn-php

Comment: Maintained but extremely problematic. Not the dev's fault, but Sony keeps switching up their auth flow. Also, it should be noted that `psn-php` repo is a workaround of sorts and hence is susceptible to failures.

Comment: As of this writing so does this wrapper only return PS4 games when asking for a users list of games. PS3 and PS Vita is not returned.